# Replication to iriscouch fails

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I am trying to build a sample application using couchapp, couchdb. I am also using the jquery.couch.js plugin to communicate with my local couchdb. However when I try to replicate it to my remote couch on iriscouch.com, I get the following error:

```
Replication failed: {error,
{{badarg,
     [{erlang,list_to_existing_atom,["data_size"]},
      {couch_rep,'-dbinfo/1-lc$^0/1-0-',1},
      {couch_rep,'-dbinfo/1-lc$^0/1-0-',1},
      {couch_rep,do_init,1},
      {couch_rep,init,1},
      {gen_server,init_it,6},
      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]},
 {child,undefined,"6f5beff2bd381e02b602cee2e8e1e86d",
     {gen_server,start_link,
         [couch_rep,
          ["6f5beff2bd381e02b602cee2e8e1e86d",
           {[{<<"source">>,<<"zwaroop">>},
             {<<"target">>,
              <<"http://username:password@swaroopsm.iriscouch.com/zwaroop">>}]},
           {user_ctx,<<"root">>,
               [<<"_admin">>],
               <<"{couch_httpd_auth, cookie_authentication_handler}">>}],
          []]},
     temporary,1,worker,
     [couch_rep]}}}
```

Where am I go wrong?

Comment: Is that a real root password ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu 12.04 (which comes with CouchDB v1.0.1), you can use a PPA instead of installing CouchDB from source. For instance, https://launchpad.net/~novacut/+archive/daily has a backport of 1.2.0 for precise; I installed it with

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:novacut/daily
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install couchdb
```

After the upgrade to 1.2.0 the problem was solved.

**EDIT:** the Novacut repository no longer hosts package for `couchdb`, as version 1.5.0 has been included in Ubuntu Trusty (http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/couchdb).

Comment: couchdb is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 232 not upgraded. BUT it's not.it's 1.0.1

Comment: I believe the people behind Novacut (which is actually a collaborative video editor, not CouchDB itself) removed the `couchdb` package from their repository when it entered 14.04 more than a year ago; as a consequence, `apt-get` is using the version in the official Ubuntu archives. That's unfortunate if you have to stick with 12.04 I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if that is a version mismatch? What version of CouchDB are you using on your local system?

Anyway, a quick workaround would be to edit the source code of CouchDB and insert `data_size` anywhere in the code.

For example, `src/couchdb/couch_doc.erl`

```
-spec to_path(#doc{}) -> path().
to_path(#doc{revs={Start, RevIds}}=Doc) ->
    data_size, % This no-op expression allows list_to_existing_atom
    [Branch] = to_branch(Doc, lists:reverse(RevIds)),
    {Start - length(RevIds) + 1, Branch}.
```

However hopefully we can find something better than this by identifying your versions.

Comment: My local couchdb version is 1.0.1. But iriscouch hosts 1.2.0. I tried to install it from the source. However it didn't work for me. :(